# How to delete worldborders in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to set the worldborders in Minecraft. But can I delete worldborders in Minecraft and if I can, how?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Easy! 
in an always active repeating command block at world spawn

```
/execute [Username here] ~ ~ ~ /worldborder center ~ ~
```

Comment: This will kill all mobs outside of the world border. OP wants the world to not be affected by the world border.

Comment: This also will create portal syncing issues (if you put a nether portal that would correspond to a spot outside of the worldborder), multiplayer issues (players have to be near the "main" player), and wouldn't work in other dimensions (Spawn chunk loading conditions). This should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

The world border is always present in a Minecraft world, even before the `/worldborder` command has been used. You can set it back to its default state (center 0,0 and width 60,000,000) by running:

```
/worldborder center 0 0
/worldborder set 60000000
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I might add that if your border isn't centered and is too small, moving it to 0,0 before growing it could affect your world (Kill all mobs), so I would recommend running the commands in the opposite order

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, but that isn't possible.
The world ends couple hundred blocks away from the world border.